# jQuery nested sortables - display issues during sorting/dropping

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got a sortable group of items with 1 level of child items. I need the child items to be sortable as well as droppable onto other items, and I need the parent items to also be sortable (but not droppable on each other or on child items.) I've ALMOST got this working correctly. Originally, I used Sortables for the parents and Draggable/Droppable for the children, but that didn't let me sort the children. I'm now using the common nested sortable setup where the sortable is connected to itself. This works okay for the children, but when I try to sort the parents, the DOM starts... well check out the fiddle below to see for yourself :)

http://jsfiddle.net/nVk8G/5/

I've tried setting a toleranceElement, though I've only just discovered that exists so I don't think I'm using it right. I've looked at Manuele Sarfatti's [nestedSortable](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/) plugin, which is awesome, but unfortunately doesn't work with the markup I have. I'm fairly convinced that the markup is the problem, but as you can probably guess, I can't change that.

One thing I didn't include in the fiddle above is the code I have in the `receive` event, which checks to see if the dragged item is a parent and is being dropped on a parent, in which case I call `.sortable("cancel")` to stop the item from being placed under another parent. This event is only supposed to be called when a connection between lists is called.

Any and all advice is appreciated! I've read through nearly all the questions on here relating to jQuery UI nested sortables without finding an answer. Nested sortables seem to be one of those things that work great if conditions are just right, but cause huge headaches otherwise.

One last thing, I've applied the patch [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/pull/555/files) to correct some jumpy behavior with nested sortables. You can't see that on the jsfiddle link though, obviously.